# Django Foreign key in another schema

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a MySQL database with 2 shemas (A & B).
My django app can read & write into A.
It can just read from B.

My app managed all the tables in A.
B already contains some data in a table (b).

I want to add a one to one field between A and B.
Something like this :

```
class SchemaBTableB(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_schema = 'B'
        db_table = 'b'

    [...]

class SchemaATableA(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_schema = 'A'
        db_table = 'a'

    id = models.OneToOneField(
        SchemaBTableB,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        primary_key=True
    )

    [...]
```

Unfortunately, `db_schema` does not exist.
Does someone know a solution ?

Comment: IMO, maybe you need to treat these two schemas as two different databases. `In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database.` [multiple databases config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: I tried with 2 databases and with a router but I didn't succeed. Constraint creation failed during migrations. If you have a working example, it would be great !

Answer (score 2):

I have been tried to use two databases to simulate your case, and find out the solution below:

### 1. Scenario:

1. database `schema1`, which is managed by django (read & write)
2. database `schema2`, which is *NOT* managed by django

### 2. Steps:

1. create migrations `python manage.py makemigrations` for your models
2. Generate SQL for your migration: `python manage.py sqlmigrate app 0001`. 
   (*suppose the generated migration file name is `0001_initial.py` from step 1*)

The sql for this migration should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (`id_id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE `user_info` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_info_id_id_e8dc4652_fk_schema2.user_extra_info_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_id`) REFERENCES `user_extra_info` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

If you run the above sql directly, you will be ended up with error like this:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'user_extra_info'")
```

**That's because django assumes that all your migration steps are executed in the same database**. So it can not find out the `user_extra_info` in `schema1` database.

### 3. Following Steps:

3. Explicit specify the database `schema2` for table `user_extra_info`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `user_info` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_info_id_id_e8dc4652_fk_schema2.user_extra_info_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id_id`) REFERENCES schema2.user_extra_info (`id`);
   ```
4. Manually run the revised sql in `schema1` database.
5. Tell django I have run the migration myself: `python manage.py migrate --fake`
6. Done!!

---

#### Source code For your reference:

#### `models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class UserExtraInfo(models.Model):
    # table in schema2, not managed by django
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_extra_info'


class UserInfo(models.Model):
    # table in schema1, managed by django
    id = models.OneToOneField(
        UserExtraInfo,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    name = models.CharField('user name', max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_info'
```

#### `settings.py`

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'schema1',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
    },
    'extra': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'schema2',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['two_schemas.router.DBRouter']
```

#### `router.py`

```
class DBRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.db_table == 'user_extra_info':
            # specify the db for `user_extra_info` table
            return 'extra'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.db_table == 'user_extra_info':
            # specify the db for `user_extra_info` table
            return 'extra'
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app':
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_list = ('default', 'extra')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'app':
            return db == 'default'
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks my database is created now, but I can't reach `UserInfo` in admin panel. Error said "Table 'app.user_extra_info' doesn't exist". I tried to return `extra` in `db_for_read` when `model == UserExtraInfo`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pierre I have updated the `DBRouter` class, so you can make query to `user_extra_info` now.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Error said "Table 'app.user_extra_info' doesn't exist". I tried to debug step by step in the router, but django never ask for `db_for_read` with `model._meta.db_table == 'member'`...

Comment: I have tested with the above codes in my pc, and it works well with django admin,  I can create record in `UserInfo` table. maybe u need to paste your code here for me to debug.

Comment: Well, I tried with a new project & with your code and it is working. So, I will try to figure out what is going on with my code"

Comment: Ok my bad, my mistake came from the SQL. But, I got some errors when I tried to implements my admin panel. `class UserInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name']
admin.site.register(UserInfo, UserInfoAdmin)
admin.site.register(UserExtraInfo)` raise error when I try to reach `/admin/app/userinfo/` : `(1146, "Table 'schema1.user_extra_info' doesn't exist")`

Comment: Sorry, you need to specify the database for table `UserExtraInfo ` in both `db_for_write` and `db_for_read`. Please refer to my latest edit above.

Comment: It does'nt work... if `list_display` contains `id`, then django raise the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180388/discussion-between-enix-and-pierre).

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a `OneToOne` and `ForeignKey`: since you mentioned FK specifically - I'll assume you want to actually make a foreign-key, which is done like this: `ForeignKey(SomeModel, unique=True)`

```
class ObjectTableA(models.Model):

    id = models.ForeignKey(
        ObjectTableB,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        unique=True,
    )

    [...]


class ObjectTableB(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'b'

    [...]
```

The difference between `OneToOne` and `ForeignKey` is like this:

With regards to a `OneToOne`, conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the "reverse" side of the relation will directly return a single object.

In contrast to the OneToOneField "reverse" relation, a ForeignKey "reverse" relation returns a QuerySet.

Since your app manages `TableA`, get rid of the `table_schema` and `db_table`.

In your `TableB` model, you may want to get rid of the `table_schema`

Edit: since you're sure you want a `OneToOne` you should just be able to do something like this:

```
id = models.OneToOneField(
ObjectB, 
on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
)
```

Since your `ObjectA` is managed by Django, just link it up `OneToOne` to your `ObjectB`.

Comment: My bad, I need a OneToOneField. My post is fixed.

Comment: Edited to give you a rough example in a `OneToOne` situation. The rest of my post still should be accurate.

Comment: This does not work. Constraint creation failed during migrations. I think Django can't reach B schema . In settings module, the default database name is 'A'. I tried with 2 databases connected on the same host but on different schema, but it does not work either.

Comment: I feel like there may be more at play here than just your `Model` setup, unfortunately. We routinely use multiple databases (some managed, some unmanaged with `ForeignKey`s between them) - some with pretty unique setups. Unfortunately, I've never ran into the issues you're having - sorry!

Comment: Can you share a router implementation allowing ForeignKey between 2 databases ?