# django customization of save method for change the default db

Tags: django, database, save, default

I want to customize the `save` method to change my db and also
I have connected my django project to a mysql db .

I have tried to create a user in the `shell` which is from my `models.py` :

```
>>> from adabazi_test.models import Users
>>> user = Users(user_name = 'mamad' , password= 'bikbik')
>>> user.save()
```

and here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
class Users(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(blank=False , max_length = 40)
    password = models.CharField(blank = False , max_length = 40)
```

in mysql db i have `adabazi_test` schema and `Users` schema and `save` method automatically put new instances of my `models.Users` in `adabazi_test` and i whould put them in `Users` schema.
 **How can i customize `save` method for making this change?**

Comment: you cannot change your db with save method. you need to alter your settings file for changing your db.

Comment: @Ahtisham i'm not changing my db . i have a mysql db which it contains some schemes(like tables) in it and i want to change the root of that.

Comment: Do you mean **schema** instead of "scheme"? In which case you're basically talking about saving your users to a different **database** since in MySQL _schema_ and _database_ are the same thing. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386964/django-foreign-key-in-another-schema) and the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) for an approach to this.

Comment: Title of your question is misleading. Well you need to create a model for that.

Comment: sorry . yes i mean schema!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Foreign key in another schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386964/django-foreign-key-in-another-schema)

Comment: Even if you don't have a ForeignKey (but probably you will have it), you should use the approach of the post mentioned. Note: a user password should not be saved like this in a database. Never. Ever. User proper security please.